# Print specified value from an JS object

Tags: php, jquery, json, ldap

I have a ldap_search function in my php script. I get some user information from the logged in user. I encoded it to json and set a cookie for these information. In my js, i used the jquery function parseJSON to create a js object from the cookie. Now i want to print the name of the user in a field. How can i get it worked?

**Edit: I want to handle the output from the js.**

[image: Chrome Console Log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple,

console.log(object[0].givename[0]);

Comment: This is it. I just have never worked with js objects. It is so simple and logically. I'm so dump to ask such a question. Thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help. Please do accept this answer as correct if it helped you :)

Comment: And dont consider your self a dump. We have all been there at some point of time :)